# cascade classifier detectMultiScale with reject levels

Tags: c++, opencv, cascade-classifier

I'm working on objects detection with cascade classifier on OpenCV 3.1 and VC++ 2015.
I want to force the cascade to detect only one object for each image and I want to get its accuracy score. For that, I tried to use the undocumented prototype of the method CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale with reject levels.
The documented version works good. But the version with reject levels still executing for a long time without giving any result. this is my source code below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
  using namespace cv;

String plate_cascade_name = "eu.xml";
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

CascadeClassifier cascade;
const float scale_factor(1.2f);
const int min_neighbors(3);
if (cascade.load(plate_cascade_name)) {

    Mat img = imread("c:/users/anis/desktop/voituretn/voiture1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    equalizeHist(img, img);
    vector<Rect> objs;
    vector<int> reject_levels;
    vector<double> level_weights;
    cascade.detectMultiScale(img, objs, reject_levels, level_weights, scale_factor, min_neighbors, 0, Size(60, 13), img.size(), true);
//cascade.detectMultiScale(img, objs, scale_factor, min_neighbors, 0,  Size(60, 13), img.size());
    Mat img_color = imread("c:/users/anis/desktop/voituretn/voiture1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    for (int n = 0; n < objs.size(); n++) {
        rectangle(img_color, objs[n], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 8);
//      putText(img_color, std::to_string(level_weights[n]),Point(objs[n].x, objs[n].y), 1, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
    }
    imshow("VJ Face Detector", img_color);
    waitKey(0);

}
return 0;
}
```