# DetectMultiScale never returns when calling overload with rejectLevels and levelWeights

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, cascade-classifier

I am trying to modify my OpenCV-based code to get confidences along with each detected object from a cascade classifier. When I call [the overload](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#accf96d130d9f3cf4c58bf445b7861c19&gsc.tab=0) of the `CascadeClassifier`'s `detectMultiScale` method which takes out parameters for `rejectLevels` and `levelWeights` (and pass true for `outputRejectLevels`), the call never completes. Internally, the call to `detectMultiScaleNoGrouping` finishes quickly but returns millions of objects. When I don't pass either of the extra out parameters and set `outputRejectLevels` to false, that same call returns 60 object and the rest of the function works fine.

Am I not supposed to call this overload? Or is there a different reason that it is returning so many values that the function never finishes? How can I do this correctly?

Note: I see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260899/cascade-classifier-detectmultiscale-with-reject-levels) that appears to be referencing the same problem, but it does not include much information about the problem itself and hasn't gotten any answers.

Comment: You can look at this issue:  [extended detectMultiscale fails when reject levels are requested #6022](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6022).

Comment: Thanks @Catree for the pointer -- I did a bit of digging and was able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this has been fixed in OpenCV's master branch, but not released yet (as of April 18, 2016). I have confirmed that manually applying the patch and rebuilding fixes the problem.

The relevant discussion is [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6022) and the PR that must be included to fix the problem is [this one](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/6062). It is a one-line change, so it should be easy to manually implement until they release an official build with the change included.